# Using different token a payement in ERC 721 contract

Tags: solidity, nft

a solidity newbie here. I have a question about creating a contract that will mint a NFT for a specific amount of some token. The nominal way to do this is:

```
uint256 public mint_price=0.8 ether;
```

How can I use different token than ether? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick google search I found this.

Hope it helps

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540628/how-do-i-accept-an-erc20-token-for-nft-mint-payment-instead-of-eth